# Accessing the output variable from Flow to PowerApp

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to pass the success/failure of the flow execution back to PowerApp, so the users can know if the submission was successful or not. Below is the flow `SFIncidentCreation` is like below

[image]

When trying to access the `successData` output variable back in the flow like below

```
Set(returnData,SFIncidentCreation.Run(FormObj));

If(returnData.successData = "True",
 Notify(
        "Flow has run successfully.",
        NotificationType.Success,
        2000
    ),
    Notify(
        "Flow run has failed.",
        NotificationType.Error,
        5000
    )
);
```

It throws error on `If(returnData.successData = "True",` saying

[image]

How can check if the flow was successful or not and return that data back to PowerApps so the users can know if it is failure or successful.

Answer (score 1):

In Flow use 'Respond to PowerApp or flow'
Then you add an output, I suggest you to use a text type.
Enter the name of the variable and the value of the output you want to send, let's say the name is: returnData
In PowerApp you have to use: `Set('varName',SFIncidentCreation.Run(FormObj).returnData);`

Comment: Try removing the flow from sources and then add it back again